# HTML - li icons won't resize with zoom

Tags: css

Just a small issue.
I have set the list-style-image to the url with the image I wish to use which is a 32*32px png.

Zoom in issue:
The list becomes compressed and moves into the adjacent div.

Zoom out issue:
The list become more spaced out and extends vertically downwards until the list ends.

I have tried to fix its size by setting its padding and margin to 0, as well as height and width to auto, and specific values, to no avail.

I can provide a code snippet if needed but I won't do so at the time of posting in the event that there's a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/bernardbaker/pg3xu2ca/
I've used a HTML list element with a background (sprite sheet).
You could do the same with a single column sprite sheet.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 12px;
    background-image: url('https://scotthsmith.com/projects/social-icons/blue/IconGrid.svg');
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

It also solves the zoom in and zoom out issue.